# Proper way to renew "iOS distribution certificate" using Codename One Preferences

Tags: codenameone

*Alert: **this question is not for developers using Xcode**, but for developers using "Codename One" to generate Apple certificates. If you don't know what I'm asking about, [read here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/signing.html)*

I received an e-mail with subject "Action Needed: iOS Distribution Certificate Expires in 30 Days". Its body:

> [...] Your iOS Distribution Certificate will no longer be valid in 30 days.
>   To generate a new certificate, sign in and visit Certificates,
>   Identifiers & Profiles.
>
> Certificate: iOS Distribution
>
> Team ID: xxxxxxxxxx
>
> [...]

What have I to do with "Codename One" to renew this certificate? Have I to remove all generated iOS certificates (including Push certificates) and regenerate them? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to re-run the certificate wizard and revoke the existing certificate. It will then generate new certificates for you that you can use when you resubmit your app.

Notice that this won't impact the app that's already in the store as Apple re-signs the apps when placing them in the store.

Comment: Repeating the wizard, there is the question "Do you want to generate new Push certificates?". Have I to reply "Yes", or is it not necessary?

Comment: You can do that at a later stage or you can re-do the push certificates too. Notice you can have 2 valid push certificates at once to create a smooth transition from one push certificate to the next.

Comment: Does the wizard allow to have two valid push certificates at once to create a smooth transition? Is there any tutorial or developer guide page for that?

Comment: It should. We try to revoke the oldest of the two certificates if both exist.